# При соприкосновеннии с врагом у персонажа не отнимается здоровье

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал HeathBar и наложил на него скрипт. Также есть персонаж который умеет ходить, и враг с тегом. Когда персонаж соприкасается с врагом вылетает ошибка - `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Upravlenie.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collider) (at Assets/scripts/Upravlenie.cs:113)`

Вот код персонажа:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Upravlenie : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    HealsBar hb;
    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    public float verticalImpulse;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool isGrounded;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    bool Fliped = false;
    bool Running = false;
    private uint coins = 0;
    public Texture2D coinIconTexture;
    public AudioClip coinCollectSound;

    private Animator animator;

    private CharState State
    {
        get { return (CharState)animator.GetInteger("State"); }
        set { animator.SetInteger("State", (int)value); }
    }

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        target = go.transform;
        hb = target.GetComponent<HealsBar>();
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

    public void LeftButtonDown()
    {
        speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
        Running = true;
        if (Fliped == false) 
            Flip(); 
            Fliped = true; 
    }

    public void RightButtonDown()
    {
        speedX = horizontalSpeed;
        Running = true;
        if (Fliped == true) 
            Flip(); 
            Fliped = false; 
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Running = false;
        speedX = 0;
    }

    public void A_Idle()
    {
        State = CharState.Idle;
    }

    public void OnClickJump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, verticalImpulse), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
            Running = false;
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckGround();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded && Running == true)
            State = CharState.Run;
        if (isGrounded && Running == false)
            State = CharState.Idle;
        if (!isGrounded)
            State = CharState.Jump;
        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
    }

    void CollectCoin(Collider2D coinCollider)
    {
        coins++;

        Destroy(coinCollider.gameObject);

        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(
            coinCollectSound,
            transform.position
            );
    }

   public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
            CollectCoin(collider);
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Monster"))
            hb.calculatedHeals(10);
            Debug.Log("Здоровье персонажа на данный момент:" + hb.realHeals);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        DisplayCoinsCount();
    }

    void DisplayCoinsCount()
    {
        Rect CoinIconRect = new Rect(1800, 10, 32, 32);
        GUI.DrawTexture(CoinIconRect, coinIconTexture);

        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.fontSize = 30;
        style.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        style.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;

        Rect labelRect = new Rect(CoinIconRect.xMax, CoinIconRect.y, 60, 32);
        GUI.Label(labelRect, coins.ToString(), style);
    }


    private void CheckGround()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 0.45F);

        isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;
    }
}


public enum CharState
{
    Idle,
    Run,
    Jump
}
```

Вот код HealthBar`а

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealsBar : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxHeals;
    public Texture HealsTexture;

    private float BarWidth;
    public float realHeals;
    private float TextureWidth;


    void Start()
    {
        BarWidth = Screen.width / 4;
        realHeals = maxHeals;
        TextureWidth = BarWidth;
    }




    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 10, BarWidth, 40), realHeals + " / " + maxHeals);

        if (HealsTexture != null && TextureWidth > 0)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(10, 30, TextureWidth, 15), HealsTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleAndCrop, true, 10.0f);
        }
    }



    public void calculatedHeals(float dmg)
    {
        if (realHeals - dmg > 0)
        {
            realHeals = realHeals - dmg;
            TextureWidth = BarWidth * (realHeals / maxHeals);
        }
        else
        {
            realHeals = 0.0f;
            TextureWidth = 0.1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь, если мало информации спрашивайте!

Comment: А при соприкосновении с монетой? Кстати, у вас в проверке коллизии после монстра скобок нет

Comment: @eastwing всё нормально, монетка собирается очки начисляются. Просто метод с монетой в этом скрипте а метода отнимания здоровья в другом

Comment: Вы target инициализируете ПОСЛЕ того, как получаете его компонент. Думаю, дело в этом

Comment: @eastwing сейчас проверю

Comment: @eastwing Изменил код, нечего не изменилось. Вы имели ввиду то что я переделал?

Comment: Да. А Юнити при запуске игры не ругается на то, что вы получаете компонент с трансформа, а не ГО?

Comment: @eastwing P.S. перезалил код на форуме

Comment: @eastwing нет, не жалуется

Comment: Проблема, как следует из ошибки, однозначно в обработчике коллизий. Либо у вас что-то не так с объектом, представляющим монстра, либо с hb. Сам проверить не могу - нет Юнити под рукой, но посмотрите на компоненты монстра, сравните их с компонентами монеты. Плюс попробуйте вывести в консоль hb

Comment: @eastwing как вывести hb? Debug.Log(hb) ?

Comment: да, прямо так. Можно попробовать вывести какое-то его поле, смотртие сами

Comment: @eastwing пишет что hb равен null, из-за чего так?

Comment: попробуйте так: `hb =go.GetComponent<HealsBar>();`

Comment: @eastwing всё равно равен нулю

Comment: Компонент точно на объекте есть?

Comment: @eastwing не очень понял вас, приведите пример